# Beautiful Soup - making a list

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been at it for several days in the soup trying to scrape a simple html structure into a list to make a dataframe.  If it was html tables i have no problem.  I am working with a structure like:

```
   <div class="someTypeofRow">
       <a href="/mainpage/choc.html">
        Chocolate flavor
       </a>
       <span class="yearText">
        (2009)
       </span>
       <br/>
       <a href="/mainpage/van.html">
        Vanilla flavor
       </a>
       <span class="yearText">
        (2004)
       </span>
       <br/>
```

And I hope to make a list out of it such that could be put into a dataframe

```
list = [ ('/mainpage/choc.html', 'Chocolate flavor', '2009') ,
             ('/mainpage/van.html', 'Vanilla flavor', '2004' )]
```

I am able to get href so far:

```
firstlist = []
jims = soup.find(class_='someOtherRow')
for jim in jims.find_all('a', href=True): 
    if jim.text: 
        firstlist.append(jim['href'])
print(firstlist)
```

I am able to get the text stuff separately:

```
car_elems = soup.find(class_='someOtherRow')
d1 = car_elems.find_all_next(string=True)
for car_elem in car_elems:
    print (d1)
```

but i can't seem to put it all together or iterate correctly.  thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `<a>` tags whose `href=` begins with `"/mainpage"` and then do `.find_next()` for `<span class="yearText">`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
       <div class="someTypeofRow">
       <a href="/mainpage/choc.html">
        Chocolate flavor
       </a>
       <span class="yearText">
        (2009)
       </span>
       <br/>
       <a href="/mainpage/van.html">
        Vanilla flavor
       </a>
       <span class="yearText">
        (2004)
       </span>
       <br/>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('a[href^="/mainpage"]'):
    all_data.append((a['href'], a.get_text(strip=True), a.find_next('span', class_='yearText').get_text(strip=True) ))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['URL', 'Flavour', 'Year'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   URL           Flavour    Year
0  /mainpage/choc.html  Chocolate flavor  (2009)
1   /mainpage/van.html    Vanilla flavor  (2004)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej for this, it was most helpful and got me moving!